# How do I test which class an object is in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c

How do I test whether an object is an instance of a particular class in Objective-C? Let's say I want to see if object a is an instance of class b, or class c, how do I go about doing it?

Answer (score 349, accepted):

To test if object is an instance of class a:

```
[yourObject isKindOfClass:[a class]]
// Returns a Boolean value that indicates whether the receiver is an instance of 
// given class or an instance of any class that inherits from that class.
```

or

```
[yourObject isMemberOfClass:[a class]]
// Returns a Boolean value that indicates whether the receiver is an instance of a 
// given class.
```

To get object's class name you can use `NSStringFromClass` function:

```
NSString *className = NSStringFromClass([yourObject class]);
```

or c-function from objective-c runtime api:

```
#import <objc/runtime.h>

/* ... */

const char* className = class_getName([yourObject class]);
NSLog(@"yourObject is a: %s", className);
```

**EDIT:** In Swift

```
if touch.view is UIPickerView {
    // touch.view is of type UIPickerView
}
```

Comment: don't forget to #import <objc/runtime.h> for class_getName()

Comment: There is also [a class method](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/Reference/Reference.html) for this.

Comment: My understanding is that this only works for objects that inherit NSObject.

Comment: @Henrik P.: or objects that conform to the NSObject protocol

Comment: @afEkenholm - but not on iOS 4.x, just so we know.

Comment: The class method specified by afEkenholm is only for mac apps, not [ios](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: @Vladimir - is there a way to get the class name as a NSString directly?

Comment: @tea, yes. see Henrik's answer

Comment: @Vladimir oh thanks - sorry didn't spot this one. My problem was that conversion to NString required explicit encoding and I'm not quite sure how this is defined in this case.

Comment: @tea, `NSStringFromClass([yourObject class])` can get the name of a class as an NSString.

Comment: What is the advantage to using `class_getName` over `NSStringFromClass`? If there is none, this answer should be adjusted.

Comment: @Yar class_getName maybe 10 times faster then NSStringFromClass! And with NSStringFromClass using more memory space. and one more thing class_getName a bit slower then isKindOfClass. And I recommend not use so often constructions with isKindOfClass or class_getName. Will be better to have your own type, it's faster for your app.

Comment: @SAKrisT and does that 10x faster diminish if I turn the `char*` into an `NSString` right after?

Comment: @Yar it's 10x faster if you will compare char* with C function strcmp

Comment: @SAKrisT and that logic can be applied to almost all uses of Objective-C vs. C. If you've got the training/expertise, go for the 10x faster. For the rest of us, code that can be trusted and easily understood is worth the trade-off. Objective-C is still quite fast, especially for those of us coming from VM langs like Java and Interpreted langs like Ruby.

Comment: Also you can use NAMEOF(obj) instead of class_getName(obj). From objc.h header - #define NAMEOF(obj)     object_getClassName(obj)

Comment: Your example of `[a class]` is confusing to a beginner. It would be better to use something like `[UIButton class]`.

Comment: Or simpler: `const char* className = 
object_getClassName(yourObject);`

Comment: I should note that calling `[yourObject class]` leaves `yourObject` free to override the `class` implementation and return anything it wants.  While unusual, this isn't unheard of in situations like `NSProxy`s, `NSDistantObject`s, and the like.  `object_getClassName()` asks the runtime directly what the real class of instance is— it's similar to reading the `yourObject->isa` struct field in the old Obj-C 1 runtime.

Answer (score 22):

You also can use

```
NSString *className = [[myObject class] description];
```

on any NSObject

Comment: This may or may not work based on whether the programmer has overridden the description method. Using [object class] or NSStringFromClass always returns the class name, though.

Comment: Good for debugging and knowing what type your mystery object is!

Answer (score 3):

What means about **isKindOfClass** in Apple Documentation

Be careful when using this method on objects represented by a class cluster. Because of the nature of class clusters, the object you get back may not always be the type you expected. If you call a method that returns a class cluster, the exact type returned by the method is the best indicator of what you can do with that object. For example, if a method returns a pointer to an NSArray object, you should not use this method to see if the array is mutable, as shown in the following code:

```
// DO NOT DO THIS!
if ([myArray isKindOfClass:[NSMutableArray class]])
{
    // Modify the object
}
```

If you use such constructs in your code, you might think it is alright to modify an object that in reality should not be modified. Doing so might then create problems for other code that expected the object to remain unchanged.

Comment: Your example code is not correct. You will only run into problems if you test for NSArray, which is immutable anyway. If you want to test for a specific class, you should use isMemberOfClass instead.

Comment: @futureelite7 This is an example of how *not* to test for class type. The [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSObject_Protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSObject/isKindOfClass:) states that `-isKindOfClass:` & `-isMemberOfClass:` should not be used to identify objects within a class cluster.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to check for a specific class then you can use

```
if([MyClass class] == [myClassObj class]) {
//your object is instance of MyClass
}
```

Answer (score 1):

if you want to get the name of the class simply call:-

```
id yourObject= [AnotherClass returningObject];

NSString *className=[yourObject className];

NSLog(@"Class name is : %@",className);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also check run time. Put one breakpoint in code and inside (lldb) console write

```
(lldb) po [yourObject class]
```

Like this..

[image]