# Can I put different types of objects in the same NSMutableArray?

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsmutablearray

I have classes A and B.
Can I put these classes in the same NSMutableArray without problems in future?

Example:

```
NSMutableArray *maincoll = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
ClassA *ca = [[classA alloc] init];
ClassB *cb = [[classB alloc] init];
//here is case
[maincoll addObject:ca];
[maincoll addObject:cb];
...
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Yes.  No limitations.  The only thing you have to be careful of is when you retrieve items from the array to verify their class (if necessary) before starting to use them.

Comment: ANd how do you verify their classes?

Comment: google: "objective-c find class of object".  First hit:

http://stackoverflow.com/a/2056036

Summary: "[yourObject isKindOfClass:[a class]]"

Comment: The for loop can do this for you. For example with a NSArray *containter: for (NSString *string in container) { // do whatever }; goes in and takes all the NSString objects and does something and then you can do: for (NSWhatever *whatever in container) { // do something else };

Answer (score 8):

Yes.

This may be the shortest answer I've ever posted.

Answer (score 0):

You can put objects of different classes. They just need to inherit from NSObject. Don't forget to release after adding to the array.

Comment: No, they don't need to inherit from `NSObject`. They just need to be Objective-C objects, i.e. of `id` type.

Comment: I'll phrase my comment as a question, can you ensure that id types will respond to retain/release messages? from what I understand you can't.

Comment: They don't need to. Check `addObject:` prototype in [NSMutableArray Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOS/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: You're right as the definition for addObject: is - (void)addObject:(id)anObject. If you do insert an id type which doesn't inherit from NSObject, is it your responsibility to ensure that it responds to the retain/release messages the array will send to it, or will the NSArray know not to.

Comment: @mouviciel, the interface does say `id`, but if you try to add an object that doesn't implement the `NSObject` protocol to a `NSArray`, the `addObject:` call will throw an exception. You can easily try with a `Class` object: `[array addObject:[NSArray class]];`