# Best way to represent a maybe type in Objective C without using pointers, (a pointer to a pointer is not an object?)

Tags: objective-c, option-type

What is the best way to represent a maybe type in Objective C without using pointers?
I can not simply use a pointer to a pointer to an object, because a pointer to a pointer to an object is not an object, and I need it to be an object.

I know one way to do this is to have a custom class for each object I have, which would result in classes like, MaybeEmployee, MaybeOrderStatus, and many more custom classes. This would work, but it seems kludgy, and not like a very good solution at all.

The second way to do it, having simply a Maybe class also seems wrong. The lack of type safety is just plain bad.

Comment: creating interface and `respondsToSelector` call is not sufficient?

Comment: You can just use the object and get the class directly.  See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2055940/how-to-get-class-name-of-object-in-objective-c

Comment: @MarekSebera I don't understand what you mean by that comment, can you go into more detail?

Comment: `+[NSNull null]` is generally used for this. Afterwards check your objects: `if((NSNull *)myObject == [NSNull null]) {...}`

Comment: @hotpaw2 so you are suggesting that I should simply have one maybe type, discard static type safety and use dynamic type checking instead? I already mentioned that possibility, but it's fair enough if you think that that's the way to go.

Comment: @lef2 I think that approach doesn't work. Every [NSNull null] points to the same instance, I want to do something like [[Maybe alloc] initWithNothing], but stronger typed.

Comment: Forget any maybe types.  The Employee and OrderStatus objects can tell you their class directly.  No other objects needed.

Comment: @hotpaw2 That doesn't make sense. How would I create a nothing object, unless I had a Maybe type? Using nil wouldn't work, because I can't mutate an object to be nil.

Comment: An Employee object with a nil employee name or employee number (etc.) would be of the Employee class.

Comment: @hotpaw2 that's basically what I'm doing right now; however, it's not a good solution. I would like to do one assignment to make an instance nil, like self.contents=nil, but with better type safety.

Answer (score 1):

lef2 has the right idea. Use NSNull to represent the "maybe not" case.

The simplest way to handle it is to make your method return an object of type id, but as you say, that sacrifices type safety.

I'd suggest creating an ancestor class MaybeClass and make all your classes derive from that. Then you can create a specific subclass maybeNot that is really an NSNull.

Note that you can also just use standard objects, and return nil when the result of a method call is empty. Objective C handles nil object pointers much more cleanly than a lot of other languages. It's perfectly valid to send messages to a nil object. They just get dropped.

Comment: Using `nil` isn't a useful substitute, but the `MaybeClass` sounds promising.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what a "maybe type" means to you, but is there a reason why `id` isn't sufficing?

Comment: A maybe type is a parametrically polymorphic type which for some type a is a nothing value, (not a null value), or a just a value. The key reason nothing is different from null is that one can make a setToNothing method, a setToNull method wouldn't make sense.

Answer (score 0):

I am also unsure what you mean by a "maybe type"! Could a protocol be what you want with some classes implementing the protocol and others not. They you can check if objects implement it or not [yourObject conformsToProtocol:@protocol(yourProtocol)]. I hope this helps but if not some more clarification would be good.