# How to check what class was an object initialized in Objective C

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, nsobject

Is it possible to check and get the name of the class an object was initialized in?

Example: I have Class A. I created object ABObject using `[[ABOBject alloc] init];` via an instance method.

How can I find out the class from which an instance ABObject was created, namely "A" here?

Comment: Take a look: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2055940/1758762

Comment: Can you explain why you need this information? It smells of a strange design.

Comment: I need this info because I have a class for an object which I want to act differently in both the other classes. So I wanted to hardcode this little feature into it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Objects can be created outside the context of a class, so it wouldn't make sense for this to be a built-in language feature.

If you do have to do this, one way to work around it would be to use the `objc_setAssociatedObjects()` function in `objc/runtime.h` immediately after any such object was instantiated. Something like:

```
ABObject *object = [[ABObject alloc] init];
objc_setAssociatedObject(object, @"InstantiatingClassKey", [self class], OBJC_ASSOCIATION_ASSIGN);
```

Then you could get it with `objc_getAssociatedObject(object, @"InstantiatingClassKey")`.

I think you'd be better off re-assessing your design because this is not going to be particularly maintainable. Even extracting this into a category on `NSObject` to remove duplicated code you'll still have an extra step to remember and weird relationships between your objects.

Also, as Martin R. points out in the comments, I'm taking a shortcut and passing a string literal as the key argument for the function, in reality you'd want to follow the practice of using the address of some static or global variable.

Comment: Minor remark: Your example relies on the fact that  `@"InstantiatingClassKey"` is a compile time constant. I think the recommended pattern is `objc_setAssociatedObject(object, <address_of_some_static_var>, ...)`.

Comment: @MartinR you're absolutely correct, I took a shortcut for illustrative purposes.