# called NSLog's function's location in project

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, nslog

I have a big project and there are many `NSLog()` calls. When something happens some `NSLog()` works, and I don't know which `NSLog` get called. How can I find a place where is `NSLog()` get called in class file?

My `NSLog` is like this: `NSLog(@"%@", someArray);`

and here's the log:

```
2013-04-23 20:43:38.257 myProj[2101:707] {
    id = 1;
    version = 1;
}
```

What does `myProj[2101:707]` mean here? Does it give me any information about `NSLog` function's location in class?

Answer (score 6):

You could try searching the project for the output.

For instance if the output is

```
This is my output with values 3.1415 and 1.2345.
```

press <kbd>cmd</kbd><kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>F</kbd> and search for "This is my output with values"

You can also insert placeholders in the search term:

[image]

Comment: interested to learn how to insert the pattern into the finder.. can explain a bit more than that.. would appreciate that..

Comment: Click the magnifying glass icon on the left of the text field

Answer (score 1):

Convert all of your NSLog usage to DLog and then the log statements will print:

1. The file name
2. The method name
3. The line number

Of every line that is output to the log. In this way you can immediately see where all logging is being done. DLog is a much better logging mechanism to use than NSLog and you should start using it in all your projects.

Define DLog in you pch file as:

```
#ifdef DEBUG
#   define DLog(fmt, ...) NSLog((@"%s [Line %d] " fmt), __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, __LINE__,  ##__VA_ARGS__);
#else
#   define DLog(...)
#endif
```

Comment: Does this even help to answer the question? DLog  can be defined as  alternative of NSLog, but it does not help the OP to find out which NSLog is called.

Comment: @nsgulliver Actually if OP replaced all NSLogs with DLogs, he would find the call he is looking for.

Comment: @nsgulliver I've updated the answer to make it more clear how DLog is a good solution.

Comment: @Wain that's much better +1.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [the function `class_getName`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2056036/213685) to get the class name of the object your log statement is placed and include the class name in `NSLog()`.

Like this:

```
#import <objc/runtime.h>
…
NSLog("%@ Some Log Statement", class_getName([self class]));
```

Comment: That's a good point for the future, but I guess OP has a hard time locating the right NSLog statement in the first place.