# Check the name of object in array

Tags: objective-c

I have `NSMUtableArray` , which i need to get the objects name in it .

```
NSMutableArray *array1 =[NSMUtableArray alloc]init];
[array1 addObject:me];
//me is another array ]
```

How can i get the name of the object `me`, looking in `array1` ?

Comment: What do you mean by the *name* of object `me`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I test which class an object is in Objective-C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2055940/how-do-i-test-which-class-an-object-is-in-objective-c)

Comment: Objects don't have names. Variables don't have any intrinsic relationship to their values; they're just labels to make coding easier.

Comment: Are you looking for the classname of me then NSLog("%@",[[array1 objectAtIndex i] class]);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what you are looking for? The dictionary contains key-value pairs.

```
NSArray *arrayOfKeys = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"firstObj",@"secondObj", nil];
YourObjectclass *firstObject = ...;
YourObjectclass *secondObject = ...;
NSArray *arrayOfValues = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:firstArray,secondArray, nil];
NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:arrayOfValues forKeys:arrayOfKeys];

[dict objectForKey:@"firstObj"]; // return (YourObjectclass*)firstObject
```

In your case, do the opposite. Swap arrays of keys and values​​. So, you can get the name of your object, if you will use object as key, and name of the object as value.